# Running mongodb $geoWithin without a [long,lat] array

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb `$geoWithin` query as followed

```
db.test.find(
         {
          'loc': {
             $geoWithin: {
                 $geometry: {
                        type : "Polygon" ,
                        coordinates: [[list of co-ordinates]]
                  }
              }
            }
          }
 );
```

So here the query runs on the `loc` field which is a array of `lng`, `lat` values but fortunately in my data, `lat` and `lng` values are in 2 different fields like

```
{
   lat:12,
   long:122
}
```

In this case how can I run the above query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing you can do really is to tranform your documents to store the data better. By preference you should probably go for GeoJSON format. But more later.

Fortunately since [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) does not actually "require" an index ( but it really still is the better option to have one ) you can actually do the transformation "on the fly" with the aggregation framework instead:

### Transform "On the Fly"

---

Hoping you have at least **MongoDB 2.6**, there is [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Tranform to array
    { "$project": {
        "location": {
            "$map": {
                "input": ["lng","lat"],
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el", "lng" ] },
                        "$long",
                        "$lat"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }},

    // Then match
    { "$match": {
        "location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon" ,
                    "coordinates": [[list of co-ordinates]]
                 }
            }
        } 
    }}
])
```

**MongoDB 3.2** has a much simpler syntax:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Tranform to array - pretty simple huh!
    { "$project": {
        "location": ["$long","$lat"]
    }},

    // Then match
    { "$match": {
        "location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon" ,
                    "coordinates": [[list of co-ordinates]]
                 }
            }
        } 
    }}
])
```

Or if you still have **MongoDB 2.4** - Upgrade! Okay, use this then:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Add an array field
    { "$project": {
        "long": 1,
        "lat": 1
        "location": { "$const": [ "A", "B" ] }
    }},

    // Unwind it
    { "$unwind": "$location" },

    // Group back and map it!
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "location": {
            "$push": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$location", "A" ] },
                    "$long",
                    "$lat"
                ]
            }
        }
     }},

    // Then match
    { "$match": {
        "location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon" ,
                    "coordinates": [[list of co-ordinates]]
                 }
            }
        } 
    }}
])
```

---

### Tranform "Permanently"

---

But really the best case is to change the document structure permanantly. The modern way to do this is in [bulk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) with something like:

```js
var ops = [];

db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {

    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": {
                "$set": { 
                    "location": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [doc.long,doc.lat]
                    }
                },
                "$unset": { "long": "", "lat": "" }
            }
        }
    });

    // Send once in 1000 only
    if ( ops.length % 1000 == 0 ) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
})

// Clear remaining queue
if ( ops.length > 0 )
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

But generally speaking, loop the source documents and update each one to create the new "location" field. Then of course "index" it:

```js
db.collection.createIndex({ "location": "2dsphere" })
```

And now the documents look like that and actually have an index, you can use regular `$geoWithin` queries directly which will also work faster from the present indexed data.

Comment: tried to run below query 
`db.getCollection('test').aggregate([

    // Tranform to array - pretty simple huh!
    { "$project": {
        "location": ["longitudeDegrees","latitudeDegrees"]
    }},

    // Then match
    { "$match": {
        "location": {
            "$geoWithin": {
                "$geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon" ,
                    "coordinates": [[[0,0], [0,6], [6,6], [6,0] ]]
                 }
            }
        } 
    }}
])`
and got this error 
**exception: disallowed field type Array in object expression (at 'location')**

Comment: @BiJ Read **Carefully**. That is only valid for MongoDB 3.2 releases, which is the latest. Chances are you need the `$map` version, which is why it's on top.

Comment: @BiJ Also you missed the variables. If your fields are actually named `"longitudeDegrees"` then you rather do it like this: `{ "$project": { "location": [ "$longitudeDegrees","$latitudeDegrees"] } }`. But again, that only works for MongoDB 3.2.x releases. The other release methods are all shown.

Comment: sorry my mistake. I was running mongo 3.0.5 so I guess this will not apply for me.
I tried to run the query with $map with the following coordinates [0,0], [0,6], [6,6], [6,0], [0,0].
the query executed fine but I have one collection `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56dffa8f010fc3915d4d8c82"),
    "latitudeDegrees" : 3,
    "longitudeDegrees" : 3
}` 
which is not showing in the result. The result is empty

Comment: The query I executed is 
`db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{"$project":{"location":{"$map":{"input":["longitudeDegrees","latitudeDegrees"],"as":"el","in":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$$el","longitudeDegrees"]},"$long","$lat"]}}}}},{"$match":{"location":{"$geoWithin":{"$geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[0,0],[0,6],[6,6],[6,0],[0,0]]]}}}}}])`

Comment: @BiJ So just like I said before, exchange the `"$lat"` and `"$long"` used in the answer ( as that was how you asked in your question ) with `"$latitudeDegrees"` and `"$longitudeDegrees"` respectively. And of course keep the "lng","lat" ordering in the array contruction.

Comment: @BiJ No the `$map` deliberately does not try to interpolate the variables but "swaps" them instead. Things with a `$` are meant to have one, and things without the `$` are also meant to be like that. You are changing around the wrong values. Follow what is actually written